# Find Admin ID of App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have access to files used in my facebook app so I can run scripts with app.

I'm looking to find out what facebook account has admin ownership of my app.

Whats the best way to do this?

Thanks

Alan

Answer (score 1):

You can request an app token for the app and then make a graph call to the app endpoint:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/<app-id>?fields=creator_uid,roles`

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application